# Add css-class to href-link according to the target URL

Tags: css, links

Imagine you put a link in your WordPress post, for example to `https://green.example`. You also set a link to `https://red.example` and to `https://yellow.example`. I would like to make it such that depending on the target URL of a link, a CSS class is automatically assigned to the link.

For example `https://green.example` should be assigned the class "green", `https://red.example` the class "red" and so on.

It should be definable for which links these classes should be assigned, not only for exact URLs (like `https://green.example/example/hello.php`), but also by rules like "for all URLs starting with `https://green.example`*".

Does anyone know how this can be done in a performance-saving way? Is JavaScript mandatory or can it be done with a WordPress function?

This function should ideally apply to all links, so not only within a post, but also if you use, for example, additional fields through ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with CSS 3 selectors. You can apply styles when an attribute starts with a value.  `^=` means "starts with" here.

```css
a[href^="https://green.example/"]{color:white;background-color:green}
a[href^="https://yellow.example/"]{color:black;background-color:yellow}
a[href^="https://red.example/"]{color:white;background-color:red}
```

[Here is a demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/4pj9yvLz/).

[This technique has excellent browser support](https://caniuse.com/css-sel3). 99.78% of users will be able to see it in their browsers.

Comment: Wow, this is an incredibly elegant way. I didn't expect it to be possible simply through CSS. I thought you would have to implement it with javascript or via functions.php. That's awesome :-) Thanks!